# Send props to Number Format - Material UI TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to create a TextField element to handle numerical fields. I want to handle this component dynamically,  in this way it would help me not only to manage credit card formats, telephone etc. I am using the react-number-format library in the same way as the Material-UI example does.
I'm trying to send by props "prefix" and "format" without favorable result.
I wanted to know how I should send those properties, if I have a way to do it. 
Thanks in advance !

```
function NumberFormatCustom(props) {
  const { inputRef, onChange, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <NumberFormat
      {...other}
      getInputRef={inputRef}
      onValueChange={values => {
        onChange({
          target: {
            value: values.value
          }
        });
      }}     
      thousandSeparator={","}
      decimalSeparator={"."}
      isNumericString
      prefix={props.prefix} //"$"      
    />
  );
}

NumberFormatCustom.propTypes = {
  inputRef: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

class NumberTextField extends Component {
  state = {
    numberformat: this.props.value
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const targetField = this.props.name;
    const targetValue = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      numberformat: targetValue
    });
    this.props.updateCurrentUserFieldsOnChange(targetField, targetValue);
  };

  render() {
    const { fullWidth, label, name, readOnly, prefix } = this.props;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <TextField
          fullWidth={fullWidth ? fullWidth : true}
          label={label ? label : "react-number-format"}
          name={name}
          value={this.state.numberformat}
          onChange={this.handleChange}          
          InputProps={{
            inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
            readOnly: Boolean(readOnly),
            prefix: prefix                        
          }}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You must use the customInput props which will allow you to integrate the style of material-ui. You can also pass several props to be able to control as you wish the mask. Also if you want a prefix just use the prefix props. thousandSeparator is a boolean but by default the numbers are separated by commas, if you prefer spaces you just have to add it as in my example

```js
  import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';

  import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

      <NumberFormat
        {...props}
        value={value}
        name={name}
        mask={mask}
        customInput={TextField}
        prefix={'$'}
        format={format || null}
        type="text"
        thousandSeparator={thousandSeparator ? ' ' : null}
        onValueChange={({ value: v }) => onChange({ target: { name, value: v } })}
      />
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, your suggestion was very useful. I was obfuscated with the Material-ui solution. Thank You

Comment: Why does the MUI example even do... what it does?

Comment: It seems like, NumberFormat accepts its props, but also really any props you want to pass, and those extra props just go down onto the `customInput`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have format your textfield as numberformat you can add your number format filed to FormControl field of material ui like below code.

```
<FormControl focused className="col " variant="outlined">
   <InputLabel className="mText">your label</InputLabel>
   <NumberFormat customInput={TextField} 
     variant="outlined"
     thousandSeparator={true} 
     onChange={handleChange}
     autoComplete="off"/>
</CustomFormControl>
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

i needed to pass `size` `TextField`  - ended up with this

```
 const CustomTextField = (props: TextFieldProps) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      {...props}
      size={'small'}
      id='outlined-basic'
      label='Outlined'
      variant='outlined'
    />
  )
}
<NumericFormat
  thousandSeparator
  prefix='$'
  onValueChange={values =>
    field.onChange(values.floatValue)
  }
  customInput={CustomTextField}
 />
```

or if you need any custom `endAdornment`to be passed to `TextField` this works

```
 import React from 'react'
import { NumericFormat } from 'react-number-format'
import { InputAdornment, TextFieldProps } from '@mui/material'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'

export const CustomTextFieldNumeric = (props: TextFieldProps) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      {...props}
      size={'small'}
      variant='outlined'
      sx={{ width: '100%' }}
    />
  )
}

type TProps = {
  suffix: string
  label: string
  onValuesChange: (val: number) => void
}

export function CurrencyInput({ suffix, label, onValuesChange }: TProps) {
  return (
    <NumericFormat
      defaultValue={0}
      label={label}
      thousandSeparator
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: <InputAdornment position='start'>{suffix}</InputAdornment>
      }}
      onFocus={e => e.target.select()}
      onValueChange={values => {
        if (values.floatValue) onValuesChange(values.floatValue)
      }}
      customInput={CustomTextFieldNumeric}
    />
  )
}
```