# React.js material-ui: How to format Textfield as an amount

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a material-ui Textfield which is *amount* field

I want to format it so that upon typing, the Textfield has thousands separator and decimal. And bonus, if the input is on the right side (just like in calculators)

e.g.
user types 1000000
textfield should show 1,000,000.00

See code below:

```
<TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        type="text"
                        id="debitAmount"
                        label="Amount"
                        value={debitAmount}
                        onChange={(e) => setDebitAmount(e.target.value)}
                        InputProps={{
                          classes: { input: classes.textfield1 },
                        }}
                      />
```

I'm trying to use a library called `react-number-format` but I'm having a hard time to apply it onto my textfield since the documentation lacks samples

I also tried to use `toLocaleString("en")` which was effective however the textfield can only show up to 4 numbers and I'm not sure why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ciao, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-br8l1?file=/src/index.js) a working example. I have used exactly the same example reported in Material-ui docs (simplyfied) using `react-number-format`, and to show a fixed number of decimal I used `toFixed(2)`.

Comment: I see. But how can I incorporate this with material-ui textfield? Since the design is kind of different when I use NumberFormat directly

Comment: Sorry. I think I found what I need in material-ui Textfield documentation: https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#formatted-inputs

Comment: Hi, @Giovanni  im not too familiar with react sintax, so how can i send thousandSeparator as parameter since textfield element?.

Answer (score 5):

`react-number-format` can be integrated with MaterialUI `TextField` like this:

```js
<NumberFormat
  customInput={TextField}
  onValueChange={(values) => setNumberFormatState(values.value)}
  value={numberFormatState}
  // you can define additional custom props that are all forwarded to the customInput e. g.
  variant="outlined"
/>
```

Be aware that I use `onValueChange` from `react-number-format`. Here you get the `values` object which has both the unformatted `value` and the formatted `formattedValue`. Most likely you want the bare value in state.

Comment: You can add your numberformat to Formcontrol. In this case you can use material ui styles. For more information about this please see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69722419/7387345

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is coming across this, IMO the @alexanderdavide solution is the simplest and can also be used with the react-currency-format library as well:

```
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';

 <CurrencyFormat
            customInput={TextField}
            thousandSeparator
            prefix="$"
            decimalScale={0}
            placeholder="Amount"
            label="Amount"
            onChange={handleNewAmount}
        />
```

Comment: Where to import CurrencyFormat?