# How to use comma as decimal separator in Material UI's TextField type=number component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, locale, user-input

I'm building a `React` app using `Material UI` and having trouble with a `<TextField type="number">` input component.
The field is used to add a weight in kilograms and I would like to be able to add numbers with decimals, like `3,4` for example. I can do that when typing manually, but the component only accepts a period `.` as the decimal separator (which is standard in the US for example). But because it's a Swedish site, I would like to accept a `,` (comma) as separator, or both period and comma.

There seems to be the option to fix it using another library `react-number-format`.
**Is there any way to fix it without using another library?**

I tried to change the `locale` in the Material UI `theme` but that didn't make any difference. I also changed my browser's language because some articles out there suggest that it can cause the problem, but it doesn't make a difference either. (It wouldn't be a real solution anyway, I think).
I also tried to use `<TextField inputProps={{ inputmode: 'numeric' pattern: '[0-9]*' }}>` instead of `<TextField type="number">` as suggested here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10582
But it made things worse, in Firefox I was even able to add letters to the input field when using it.

Comment: you can user react-number-format library and if you want to save your material ui style for your component ui you can check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69722419/7387345