# Adding mask to ui material Texfield fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Good night! I'm studying react and I decided to develop a registration form and I wanted to add a mask to the cpf and zip code inputs. But when I put the mask on the TextField it is out of the pattern I put on the form, I'm using the ui material in its latest version.

[image: Before adding the mask]

[image: After adding the mask]

```js
import React from 'react';
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';

const MaskCPF = () => {
  return (
    <NumberFormat 
      format="###.###.###-##"
      mask="_"
    />  
  );
}

export default MaskCPF;
```

```html
 <TextField 
        onChange={(event) => setCPF(event.target.value)}
        value={cpf}
        error={!error.cpf.valid}
        helperText={error.cpf.text}
        onBlur={validateFields}
        InputProps={{
          inputComponent: MaskCPF,
        }}
        placeholder='11122233310'
        id='cpf'
        label='CPF'
        name='cpf'
        type='number'
        variant='outlined'
        fullWidth
        margin='normal'
        required
/>
```

Comment: Did you check this question before posting? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080038/send-props-to-number-format-material-ui-textfield

Comment: Here you go, I have sandboxed this using your use case: https://codesandbox.io/s/formattedinputs-material-demo-forked-mqjztr?file=/demo.js

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already managed to make the correct implementation of the field.